# доступ к MongoDB в локальной сети

Tags: сервер, mongodb, windows-10, доступ

Есть потребность запустить на одном компьютере, под управлением win 10, сервер mongodb, а на втором компьютере, который тоже под управлением Win 10 и находится в той же локальной сети(беспроводное подключение через маршрутизатор), получить доступ к этой базе.

Как это сделать!?

По умолчанию сервер запускается на 127.0.0.1:27017 и естественно, дальше одной машины выйти не позволяет.

порт 27017 открыл через брандмауэр в обе стороны на обоих компьютерах

в .cfg файле поставил bind_ip 0.0.0.0

Попытка подключения через mongodb Compass к машине с запущенным сервером по ip пункта назначения и порту 27017 отваливаливается по таймауту

Answer (score 2):

Решено

при переустановке mongodb заметил ошибку, которая не предвещала беды.

Текст ошибки "service mongodb server failed to start verify that you have sufficient privileges"

Гугл сразу ответил, что установочный файл не на столько умный, чтобы запустить сервис когда выбран путь установки не по умолчанию.

Устанавливаем mongoDB. В конфиге прописываем bind_ip 0.0.0.0, разрешаем в брандмауэре все подключения для mongod и о чудо, всё работает так, как должно работать!

Answer (score 0):

Перезапускали mongodb? Вообще достаточно много проблем с использованием этой БД в windows.

Для начала посмотрите, какие программы какие слушаю порты. В linux это делается командой `netstat` с флагами `-tpln`. Поищите аналоги для windows. Проверьте, действительно ли монга слушает порт. В Linux в этом случае присутствует строчка:

```
tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:27017  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  15555/mongod
```

Еще можно через nmap проверить порты. Причем проверять с двух сторон. И на сервере к себе, и с клиента на сервер. Команда:

```
nmap -p 27017 localhost
```

Когда проверяете со стороны клиента, вместо localhost указать IP.

Если что-то где-то закрыто, то надо рыть в эту сторону. И использовать винду тут скорее больно, чем необходимо.